# Create All Possible Combinations Of a number in excel

Tags: excel-formula

well i want enter a number in excel and give me 4 digit Combinations Of it.how can i do that? like this i enter 8 and give me

> 2 2 2 2
>   2 3 2 1
>   5 1 1 1
>   etc

Comment: I am not sure formulas are the way to go, and doubt it is possible.  This would require VBA.

Comment: Do you need ***5 1 1 1*** separate from ***1 5 1 1*** ??

Comment: How is it going then? Please read some guidelines for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Main point is, where are you stuck in your solution.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent no.i dont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run sub `phoniX()`:

```
Sub phoniX()
    Dim N As Long, ary(1 To 4) As Long

    N = Application.InputBox(prompt:="enter value", Type:=1)
    xxx = 1

    For i = 0 To N
        For J = 0 To N
            For k = 0 To N
                For l = 0 To N
                    If i + J + k + l = N Then
                        ary(1) = i
                        ary(2) = J
                        ary(3) = k
                        ary(4) = l
                        Call LittleSort(ary())
                        Cells(xxx, 1).Value = "'" & ary(1) & ary(2) & ary(3) & ary(4)
                        xxx = xxx + 1
                    End If
                Next l
            Next k
        Next J
    Next i

    Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub

Public Sub LittleSort(ByRef InOut)

    Dim i As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
    Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(i) > InOut(i + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + J)
            InOut(i + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: thanks man you made my day.worked!